# Use if statement of parent repeater in nested repeater

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have 2 nested repeaters. I want to compare one data from the first repeater to the second one. If the data in the first repeater is the same as the data in the second repeater, I will show the some code (div, ul, li, etc.) in the second repeater. How can I do that? Here's an example:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <% if (Eval("username").ToString() == ***Repeater1Eval * **)
                    { %>
                //Show Something
                  <% }
                else
                { %>
                //Show Something
               <% } %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: My problem is that I can't use the eval on the first repater in the second repeater if statement. I want to compare Repeater1 Eval and Repeater2 Eval in the Repeater2 ItemTemplate. How can I do that? @derloopkat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, but requires a lengty inline ternary operator.

```
<%# Eval("username").ToString() == (((IDataItemContainer)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView)["username"].ToString() ? "Same username as Parent" : "" %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The problem has been solved this way: `<%# <Repeater1Eval>.ToString() == DataBinder.Eval(((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem, "<Repeater2Eval>").ToString() ? "Same username as Parent" : "" %>`